# Trying to download page in python with urllib2 and requests but keep getting redirected

Tags: python-requests, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I am trying to simply download a page with python.

http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770

If i get the response code from the server i get 200

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770'
file_pointer = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print file_pointer.getcode()
```

However if i get the url i get the redirect page

```
file_pointer.geturl()
```

I have tried urllib, urllib2,requests, and mechanize all separately and can not get any to work. I am obviously missing something because other people in the office have code that works. SOS

Also here is more information provided by requests

```
import requests

url = 'http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770'
proxy = { 'https': '200.35.152.93:1212'}
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy) 

send: 'GET /CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webapps.rrc.state.tx.us\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.10 Windows/7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 19:33:12 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
header: Location: http://www.rrc.state.tx.us/site-policies/railroad-commission-of-texas-site-policies/?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770
header: Content-Length: 405
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
send: 'GET /site-policies/railroad-commission-of-texas-site-policies/?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.rrc.state.tx.us\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.10 Windows/7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: server: one
header: Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 19:33:11 GMT
header: Content-Length: 41216
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this specific site is looking for your User Agent header, and since you're a python client, it disallows you to get the PDF and redirect you.

Therefore you need to mask your user agent.

Look at the following example:

```
url = 'http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_unredirected_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')

file_pointer = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print file_pointer.getcode()
print file_pointer.geturl();
```

Comment: How can i use a proxy with this ?

Comment: Add urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '200.35.152.93:1212'})))

Comment: Thank you Uri. I actually had to do this same thing but in requests to get it working due to some problem with https

Answer (score 0):

Okay so all one has to do with the requests module is to disable redirection.Here is my working code that is also using a proxy server.

```
import requests

url = 'http://webapps.rrc.state.tx.us/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplP4FormPdf&packetSummaryId=97770'
proxy = { 'https': '200.35.152.93:1212'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy,allow_redirects=False) 
print r.url
```